# Append to a list of dataframes with correct object type

Tags: python, pandas

This problem is not specific to pandas I guess.
I'm trying to find all xls files in a folder, read them with pandas and write each of them to a dataframe. Afterwards I want to concatenate all dataframes to one.

In the loop, I am renaming each dataframe with a date stamp with this command (in order to keep it for later concatenation):

```
exec("%s = %s" % ('data_'+date,'data'))
```

and then append the new dataframe name to a list:

```
dataframes = dataframes + 'data_'+date
```

When I try to concatenate this list by:

```
data_total = pd.concat(dataframes)
```

I keep getting an error:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
```

I understand that making a list of strings doesn't work and that I should build a list of data frames. How do I do this? I have a bit of a problem to understand how I can make assignments when I don't have the variable name at hand explicitly.

UPDATE:
I'm posting more code for better understanding.

```
# filepaths is a list of paths to excel files in the folder

dataframes = []
for file in filepaths:
    date = file[-14:-4]                              # Read date from file name
    data = pd.read_excel(file)                       # Read excel sheet
    exec("%s = %s" % ('data_'+date,'data'))          # rename data frame
    dataframes = dataframes + 'data_'+date           # Update list of data frames for concatenation below

data_total = pd.concat(dataframes)
```

Thanks,
Sebastian

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please post all of your code, as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that we can execute, or at least read straight through. Also include the full [traceback](https://realpython.com/python-traceback/) as this is very helpful in debugging. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have added a slimmed down version.

Comment: You have to add (a copy of) `data` to dataframes, not the string `'data_'+date`.

Comment: Thanks louic. I'm making the copy by renaming. How would you then add this copy to the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic variable names is an anti-pattern. It gives the progammer a bunch of almost inaccessible object. The correct way if you want to associate a name to an object is to use a dictionary:

```
dataframes = {}
for file in filepaths:
    date = file[-14:-4]                              # Read date from file name
    data = pd.read_excel(file)                       # Read excel sheet
    dataframes[date] = data                          # store the dataframe with its date

data_total = pd.concat(dataframes.values())
```

---

But here you do not use the name, so you could use a simple list:

```
dataframes = []
for file in filepaths:
    data = pd.read_excel(file)                       # Read excel sheet
    dataframes.append(data)                          # store the dataframe

data_total = pd.concat(dataframes)
```

or with a comprehension:

```
data_total = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(file) for file in filepaths])
```

Comment: Your second suggestion solved it. `dataframes[date] = data` didn't work, however, as the index needs to be an integer, not a string. Thank you so much!

Comment: @zip Your comment suggests that you didn't copy the first example **verbatim** and created `dataframes` as a list instead of a dictionary. Lists uses indexes (integers) to look up their values, while dictionaries uses keys (unique, hashable values, such as strings) to look up their values.

Comment: Thanks @HampusLarsson, appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

You do not need to separately name your dataframes. As I understand you want to concatenate the different dataframes one under the other (along `axis=0`) and add a column with the corresponding date for each dataframe. The `date` is extracted from the name for the excel file and added to the `date` column in the final dataframe.

The solution below uses `glob` library to get a list of `.xlsx` (excel) files first. Then it uses a `list-comprehension` to punch together all the dataframes, while reading each dataframe on the fly and adding the `date` column using `pandas.Dataframe.assign()` with a **`lambda-function`**.

```py
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob

base_path = 'some_directory'
excel_files = glob(base_path + '/*.xlsx')

## Read all the excel files and store 
#  in a list of dataframes: dfs
#  >>> dfs --> dataframes
dfs = [(pd.read_excel(excel_file))
          .assign(date=excel_file[-14:4]) \
       for excel_file in excel_files]
## Consolidate all dataframes
#  >>> data_total --> consolidated dataframe
df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=0)
```

### Whole solution in a single line

```py
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob

base_path = 'some_directory'
df = pd.concat([( pd.read_excel(excel_file))
                    .assign(date=excel_file[-14:4] ) \
        for excel_file in glob(base_path + f'/*.xlsx')], 
        axis=0)
```

I suggest you not to use the variable name `data_total` as it wrongly gives an impression of the total (summed-values) of your data. If I am not wrong what you want is a consolidated dataframe of all the dataframes.

### Solution without saving dates in the final dataframe

```py
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob

base_path = 'some_directory'
excel_files = glob(base_path + f'/*.xlsx')
df = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(excel_file) for excel_file in exce_files], axis=0)
```

Comment: @zip I hope this helps. Please try it out and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I was actually just using the date to give the individual data frames a name - not adding a column to the data frame. As it is not required anymore (because I don't need the individual data frames later on), the solution becomes even simpler. Thanks so much!

Comment: @zip If you do not need the `date` column, just remove the `.assign(...)` part to avoid the extra processing.